# Use checkBox and textBox in DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, checkbox

I have created a DataList in asp.net -

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="pTextBox">

<ItemTemplate>

<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxPN" runat="server"  Checked='false' />
<asp:TextBox ID="profileTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>'></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;


</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

This creates checkBoxes and textBoxes based on the string values passed through from a webService.

How can I get the `profileTextBox` Text string value when a user clicks `CheckBoxPN` and populate another textBox outwith the DataList on the page with the string value??

Comment: "How can I get"... where?  Client-side or server-side?

Comment: pass the string value to another textBox on the page outwith the DataList I should have mentioned that. Editing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`CheckedChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged.aspx) event of the `CheckBox` and cast it's `NamingContainer` to `DataListItem`, the you just have to use `FindControl` to find a different server control:

```
protected void CheckBoxPN_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) sender;
    DataListItem item = (DataListItem) chk.NamingContainer;
    TextBox txt = (TextBox) item.FindControl("profileTextBox");
    this.OtherTextBoxOnPage.Text = txt.Text; // here we are
}
```

By the way, this approach works with any web-databound control(`Repeater`, `GridView`, etc.)

Comment: I tried you solution and added this tto the aspx -
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxPN" runat="server"  Checked='false' OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxPN_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
However if I set a break point on the "CheckBoxPN_CheckedChanged" on debugging it does not get to the event when I set a breakpoint on it and the value is not retrieved??

Comment: @Jambo: I assume that you are mistakenly databinding the DataList on postbacks. Just do it on the first load. So this might fix it in `Page_Load`: `if(!IsPostBack){DataBindDataList();}`

Comment: it would appear you are a hero. BOOM! Done! Much appreciated.